# Why does typescript error when returning a narrowed type in a function with a generic mapped return type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

A simple example makes the question more clear

```js
type T1 = {
    asdf: string
    type: "T1"
}
type T2 = {
    qwer: string
    type: "T2"
}

// discriminated on "type"
type AnyT = T1 | T2

// either of the literal discriminant values
type AnyDiscriminantOfT = "T1" | "T2"

//map the discriminant to a different type
type MappedTest<T extends AnyDiscriminantOfT> = T extends "T1" ? "foo" : T extends "T2" ? "bar" : never

//function signature works as expected, but body won't compile despite being correct
const testFn = <T extends AnyT>(arg: T): MappedTest<T["type"]> => {
    if (arg.type === "T1") {
        //Type '"foo"' is not assignable to type 'MappedTest<T["type"]>'
        return "foo"   
    } else if (arg.type === "T2") {
        //Type '"bar"' is not assignable to type 'MappedTest<T["type"]>'.
        return "bar"
    } else {
        throw new Error("invalid arg")
    }
}

const val: T1 = {asdf: "123", type: "T1"}
//fn signature is correct, typeof res is "foo"
const res = testFn(val)
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

I don't understand why this doesn't compile. TS narrows the type of `arg` within the conditional and the values being returned are correct yet TS still reports an error.

It seems that control flow analysis does not apply when TS is checking return types involving generics?

The type signature of the function is valid and correct but I can't think of a way to write the function body that compiles in TS without resorting to `any`. The other option I suppose is to use overloads instead of a mapped return type, but those can come with other surprises.

Is there any way to write this function body in TS or have I simply hit a corner case of the language?

Comment: This is a missing feature of TypeScript, see [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912). Generally speaking, checking `arg.type` narrows the type of `arg`, not the `T` type parameter (it can still be the full union).  And without narrowing `T`, there's no way for the compiler to evaluate `MappedTest<T>`. It's not trivial to address this without allowing all kinds of incorrect code. I'm confused though about why you're implementing things with generic conditional type instead of simple property lookup like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WoaJjN)?

Comment: If you remove the return type annotation (`: MappedTest<T["type"]>`) it compiles